# Caught fatal signal 11

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

i get Caught fatal signal 11 at
i have to show the first n Prime numbers
i tried to save the numbers inside a vector/array and get this error Caught fatal signal 11

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n,i=1,a=2,l=1,t,c,p=1;
    t=n;
    cin>>n;
    int v[n];

    for(c=1;c<=t;i++)
    {
        while(a<=i/2 && l==1)
        {
            if(i%a==0)
            {
                l=0;
            }
            ++a;
        }
        if(l==1)
        {
            v[p]=i;t--;
        }

        a=2;l=1;p++;
    }
    for(p=1;p<=n;p++)
    {
        cout<<v[p]<<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you step through your code with a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again to watch what happens leading up to that point?

Comment: `int v[n];` This is not standard C++.  If you need a dynamically-sized array, you should probably be using [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: Also array indices start with `0`, so `for(p=1;p<=n;p++)` will access the array past its bounds and invoke *undefined behavior*

Comment: Also `t=n;` means that `t` is in an *indeterminate* state because `n` hasn't been initialized yet, so `for(c=1;c<=t;i++)` invokes *undefined behavior*

Comment: I'd also recommend taking some time to think of better variable names.  In its current state, this code is not easy to follow.  And unless you are playing [code golf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf), there are no bonus points for using as few characters as possible.  Some names that come to mind include `primes`, `divisor`, `remainder`, `max_value_to_check`, `current_index`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Killed by signal 11 / Caught fatal signal 11 / Stopped by signal 11 occurs when there are problems with memory usage. The most common reason is "out of vector" - referring to an element that does not exist in a vector.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow and thank you for the answer. A better, answer, though, would be to explain where you felt this error was likely to be raised, that would help future users understand better the problems with the code shown here - which is trying to use a C array type as a dynamic array/vector.